# Hide user input with *** in yii2

Tags: yii2

I want to hide whatever user types in field `wpc_crewid`. I've tried with passwordInput like below -

```
<?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]wpc_crewid")->label(false)->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true,'autofocus' => 'autofocus','placeholder' => 'Crew ID No','autocomplete' => 'off','class' => 'crewid']) ?>
```

This is working, but it is showing a dropdown whenever user puts cursor on this field. I don't want this dropdown to appear.

[image]

Please let me know the workaround.

Comment: try autocomplete="off"

Comment: @RajeshYadav Doesn't work, though, I tried myself.

Comment: @Rajesh, I already have autocomplete="off".

Comment: This behavior is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2531/5812455

Answer (score 1):

now browsers have started to override the auto-complete off so adding auto-complete will not work

Browsers look for the first input type password and one more input before that considering it as username , so you can use trick to fool browsers by adding the following code at the start of your form

```
 <input style="opacity: 0;position: absolute;">
 <input type="password" style="opacity: 0;position: absolute;">
```

hope this helps :-)